# How to specify multiple event types in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Reading [D3's documentation on event handling](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#handling-events), I think it should be possible to specify multiple event types in the `.on()` call that should be handled by the same callback, like so:

```
d3.select("body").append("input").attr("type", "text")
  .on("click keypress", function () {
    console.log("fired "+d3.event);
  });
```

[Try this on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMaBxY?editors=1111)

In this example, I would expect both `click` and `keypress` events to cause the "fired" message to be printed to the console, but it doesn't work. If only one of the events is specified, it does for that single event type.

Am I misunderstanding the documentation or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: You're not misunderstanding the documentation, you're just doing the wrong reference: your codepen is using D3 v3... use v4 instead and it will work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvyqLB?editors=1111

Comment: @GerardoFurtado indeed! Make that into an answer and I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but this is just a typo... we should not answer "typo" questions. Feel free to write yourself an answer, if you think it's useful.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Actually, it is/could be more than that... is this a new feature of v4? Unfortunately I wasn't quickly able to find the documentation for v3...

Comment: Yes, that's new for v4... that's why your question is just a typo: you're using v3 but reading the docs for v4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by [GerardoFurtado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808588/how-to-specify-multiple-event-types-in-d3-js?noredirect=1#comment86635410_49808588) (Thanks for that!), specifying multiple event types is a new feature in version 4 of D3, but my CodePen used version 3 instead.

To fix it, use https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js instead of https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js in the HTML source.